# Generating Factor Scores in Confirmatory Factor Analysis (Regression and Bartletts methods)

Tags: confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am following the paper [Understanding and Using Factor Scores: Considerations for the Applied Researcher Applied Researcher](https://scholarworks.umass.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1226&context=pare) which is about constructing factor scores in a confirmatory factor analysis using different methods.

I am interested in the following methods but while the paper makes sense to me, I am not sure how to actually apply it in code (R in my case). I find if i actually see it in code and can step through the process it will help me clarify the ideas in the paper. I realize this possibly falls between a stats question and a coding question so please do delete it and I can re-post it to stack exchange if it violates the forum rules.

I am specifically interested in the Regression method and the Bartlett method summarized on page 9. I have managed to get the "Weighted
Sum Scores" working but can not get the other two methods up and working due to lack of understanding

In the example below I would like to just generate the factor score per individual for the construct `visual`. I want to use it later to compare the means between groups

```r
library(lavaan)
library(broom)
## The famous Holzinger and Swineford (1939) example
hs_mod <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3'

cfa_fit <- cfa(hs_mod, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, std.lv=TRUE)
summary(cfa_fit, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE)

# Here we pull the standardized loadings
loadings <- cfa_fit %>% 
  tidy() %>% 
  filter(op == '=~') %>% 
  select(term, op, loading = std.all) %>% 
  select(loading)

# Here we take the raw data
visual_df <- HolzingerSwineford1939 %>% 
  select(x1, x2, x3)
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Not sure if your goal is to be able to generate the scores manually, but lavaan's `lavPredict()` function has an argument where you can request regression or Bartlett factor scores.

Comment: @Terrence, Oh thank you, I didn't know about that function